# Exact position of a node in a rectangle

Tags: tikz-pgf, horizontal-alignment

> **This question led to a new package:**
>   [`fancytabs`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/fancytabs)

I have a node positioned in a shaded rectangle with:

```
\newcommand{\tabstyle}{\Large\scshape}
\newcommand{\tabheight}{4cm}
\newcommand{\tabwidth}{1cm}
\newcommand{\tabcount}{6}
\newcommand{\tableftcolor}{white}
\newcommand{\tabrightcolor}{gray!50}
\newcommand{\tabtop}{\tabheight}
\newcommand{\tabtextpos}{0.5}
\newcommand{\fancytab}[2]{%
  \begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture,overlay]
    \node[yshift={-\tabtop-1*mod(#2-1,\tabcount)*\tabheight},
                  xshift=-0.5*\tabwidth]
      at (current page.north east) {
      \tikz\shade[shading=axis,bottom color=\tableftcolor,
                  top color=\tabrightcolor,shading angle=-90]
        (0,0) rectangle (\tabwidth,\tabheight)
           node[rotate=90,pos=\tabtextpos] {\tabstyle#1};
    };
  \end{tikzpicture}%
}
```

Typically, when `\tabtextpos` has value `0.5`, the text is centered in the shape, both vertically and horizontally:

[image: 0.50, centered]

Now if I used `0.38` to put it more to the left, I get:

[image: 0.38, not centered]

which is more to the left, but also down.

How could I put it to the left while still keeping it centered vertically?

**Edit:**

This code is now part of a module called `fancytabs`, available [on CTAN](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/fancytabs).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The factor you give is between the given rectangle path coordinates `(0,0)` and `(\tabwidth,\tabheight)`. This moves it diagonal. If you don't want that you need to place it either using a different path (which doesn't has to draw anything), i.e. between `(0,.5*\tabheight)` and `(\tabwidth,.5*\tabheight)` or better directly:

```
  \tikz\shade[shading=axis,bottom color=\tableftcolor,
                  top color=\tabrightcolor,shading angle=-90]
        (0,0) rectangle (\tabwidth,\tabheight)
           node [rotate=90] at (\tabtextpos*\tabwidth,.5*\tabheight) {\tabstyle#1};
```

Note that in this implementation `\tabtextpos` must be numeric, while before it could also be a string like 'midway', 'near end', etc.

You could also the `calc` tikzlibrary syntax: `($ (0,.5*\tabheight) ! \tabwidth ! (\tabwidth,.5*\tabheight) $)`, but for this usage this would be overkill.