# A working example of fancytabs

Tags: packages, header-footer, fancytabs

I tried `fancytabs` by the example given in its manual as

```
\documentclass{scrbook}
\usepackage{scrpage2}
\usepackage{fancytabs}
\usepackage{lipsum}
% Capture chapter head
\let\oldchapter\chapter
\newcommand\temphead{}
\newcommand\chaphead{}
\renewcommand\chapter[2][\temphead]{%
\renewcommand\temphead{#2}%
\renewcommand\chaphead{#2}%
\oldchapter[#1]{#2}}
% Set central right header to display tab
% for both scrplain and scrheadings
\cohead[\fancytab{\chaphead}{\thechapter}]
{\fancytab{\chaphead}{\thechapter}}

\renewcommand*{\chapterpagestyle}{scrplain}
\pagestyle{scrheadings}
\begin{document}
\chapter{A chapter}
\lipsum
\lipsum
\end{document}
```

but it does not show the vertical lab displayed in the manual document or [HERE](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/15922/exact-position-of-a-node-in-a-rectangle). I just copied the exact example from manual. Where did I do wrong?

Comment: You have to compile twice.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The package `fancytabs` uses the package TikZ to draw the tabs. To compute the correct position of the tabs TikZ needs two compilation runs of `(pdf)latex`.