# How to adjust the fancytab command to appear on the left hand side?

Tags: fancytabs

Within the fancytabs package, there is only a command for producing the fancytab on the right-hand side of a page. I am however using this in a twosided document and so I need it appear on the left-hand side of the page for odd numbered pages but I'm unsure on how to adjust the code provided by the package itself to do this.

[fancytabs documentation](http://mirror.ox.ac.uk/sites/ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/fancytabs/fancytabs.pdf)

If this isn't possible, are there any alternatives to give a similar effect?
Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A good question!

Yes, it is possible. See the sketch of the definition `\leftfancytab` and its usage (with [A working example of fancytabs](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/52615/a-working-example-of-fancytabs) as the starting point) .

```
\documentclass{scrbook}
\usepackage{scrpage2}
\usepackage{fancytabs}
\usepackage{lipsum}
% Capture chapter head
\let\oldchapter\chapter
\newcommand\temphead{}
\newcommand\chaphead{}
\renewcommand\chapter[2][\temphead]{%
\renewcommand\temphead{#2}%
\renewcommand\chaphead{#2}%
\oldchapter[#1]{#2}}

\makeatletter
\newcommand{\leftfancytab}[2]{%
  \begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture,overlay]%
    \node[yshift={-1*(\the\tab@top+\the\tab@height/2+
                 mod(#2-1-\tab@floor,\tab@count)*
                 (\the\tab@height+\the\tab@gap))},
    %              xshift=-0.5*\the\tab@width]
  xshift=0.5*\the\tab@width]
      at (current page.north west) {
      \tikz\shade[shading=axis,bottom color=\tab@leftcolor,
                  top color=\tab@rightcolor,shading angle=-90]
        (0,0) rectangle (\the\tab@width,\the\tab@height)
           node[rotate=0]
                  at (\tab@texthpos*\the\tab@width,\tab@textvpos*\the\tab@height)
                      {\rotatebox{90}{\tab@style#1}};%
    };%
  \end{tikzpicture}%
}
\makeatother

% Set central right header to display tab
% for both scrplain and scrheadings
\cohead[\leftfancytab{\chaphead}{\thechapter}]
{\leftfancytab{\chaphead}{\thechapter}}

\renewcommand*{\chapterpagestyle}{scrplain}
\pagestyle{scrheadings}
\begin{document}
\chapter{A chapter}
\lipsum
\lipsum
\end{document}
```

[image]